# static_assert fails when test condition includes constants defined with const?

Tags: c++11, error-handling

I'm reading Bjarne Stroustrup's book, "The C++ Programming Language" and I found an example explaining  `static_assert`. What I understood is that `static_assert` only works with things that can be expressed by constant expressions. In other words, it must not include an expression that's meant to be evaluated at runtime.

The following example was used in the book (I did some changes in the code. But I don't think that should change anything that'd be produced by the original example code given in the book.)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f (double speed)
{
    constexpr double C = 299792.468;
    const double local_max = 160.0/(60*60);
    static_assert(local_max<C,"can't go that fast");
}

int main()
{
        f(3.25);
    cout << "Reached here!";
    return 0;
}
```

The above gives a compile error. Here's it compiled using ideone: http://ideone.com/C97oF5

The exact code from the book example:

```
constexpr double C = 299792.458;
void f(double speed)
{ 
    const double local_max = 160.0/(60∗60);
    static_assert(speed<C,"can't go that fast"); // yes this is error
    static_assert(local_max<C,"can't go that fast");
 }
```

Comment: I don't remember removing or adding any line in above two code snippets. You can check the edit history (if that's possible).

Comment: I apologize. I still see that line of code in your post.

Comment: The line still exists and commented with // yes this is error. Please note that there are two different code snippets included in the question. Read the question carefully and you'll understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid static assert behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951741/invalid-static-assert-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Because the code snippet in the book is a mistake and is simply not correct, it was later corrected in a different book by the same author in the 2nd edition of the "A tour of C++" book.

The mistake was that

```
const local_max = 160.0/(60*60);
```

couldn't be used in

```
static_assert(local_max<C,"can't go that fast");
```

because the `const` variables are evaluated at run-time while `static_assert(...)`  requires compile time variables. `constexpr` , however, is evaluated during compile time and hence can be used in the `static_assert(...)` function.
Hence the correct way to define local_max is by using the `constexpr` keyword and not `const`

```
constexpr local_max = 160.0/(60*60);
```

Old (Incorrect) Snippet as found in "The C++ Programming Language" book

```
constexpr double C = 299792.458; // km/s
void f(double speed) {
    const double local_max = 160.0/(60*60); // 160 km/h == 160.0/(60*60) km/s
    static_assert(speed<C,"can't go that fast"); // error: speed must be a constant
    static_assert(local_max<C,"can't go that fast"); // OK // ...
}
```

Updated (Correct) Snippet as found in "A Tour of C++ (second edition)"

```
constexpr double C = 299792.458; // km/s
    void f(double speed) {
        constexpr double local_max = 160.0/(60∗60); // 160 km/h == 160.0/(60*60) km/s
        static_assert(speed<C,"can't go that fast"); // error: speed must be a constant
        static_assert(local_max<C,"can't go that fast"); // OK // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know the value of `speed` at compile time. It makes sense that it cannot evaluate `speed < C` at compile time. Hence, a compile time error is expected when processing the line

```
static_assert(speed<C,"can't go that fast");
```

---

The language does not guarantee that floating point expressions be evaluated at compile time. Some compilers might support it but that's not to be relied upon.

Even though the values of the floating point variables are "constants" to a human reader, they are not necessarily evaluated at compile time. The error message from the compiler from the link you provided makes it clear.

> ```
> static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
> ```

You'll have to find a way to do the comparison using integral expressions. However, that seems to be a moot point. I suspect, what you really want to do is make sure that `speed` is within a certain limit. That makes sense only as a run time check.

Comment: Look at the code that's compiled in ideone.com. It doesn't include the line you're talking about, but still gives an error.

Comment: Thanks. With your updated answer would it be fine arguing that the book itself does comparison with `double` values and commented that it should be okay.